# How to set up a two column layout with scroll on one side with Appium?

Tags: python, pycharm, appium, appium-android

I have a application which has 2 columns with 1st column at left side scrollable and right side - when left element is clicked it will display at 2nd column. How can I handle this scrolling?

Steps:

1. Open App
2. Scroll at 1st column till the element needed is visible
3. Click on that element, go to 2nd column
4. Select element on 2nd column and get data from which ever is displayed.

I tried Swipe from top to bottom, but how do I select only 1st column which is scrollable and find an element which is needed in that?

I couldn't find a solution. Please can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.